# Hide a particular field of case class while converting to json

Tags: json, scala, spray

I am using spray for my REST services in scala. I have a case class, `User` which contains fields as username, firstname, lastname, password etc. I want to remove the field `password` while converting to json. I am using `muster` library for json conversion. How can I achieve this?

I do not want to create a copy of case class and reset the password field.

Comment: Its 6 years later, and do we have a better way to achieve this? (Than using `copy()` method on case class?)

Answer (score 0):

Have a model for the internal representation of the data and a second model for exporting the data and map between them.  This would all take place before your json serialization framework of choice.

If you insist on having a single model then make password an `Option[String]` (assuming it is currently a String) and when you are going to export you do `user.copy(password = None)` to clear out the password.  I don't know how muster does it, but in spray-json a field that is an option will not be serialized if it is None.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I was looking for something like '@JsonIgnore' and '@JsonProperty' in Jackson (Java). It automatically ignore the field while converting to json.

Comment: @YaduKrishnan I recommend following Gangstead's advice. In my projects that use `spray-json` I have pairs of `model.User` and `serialization.UserWire` case classes. Such separation also simplifies future re-factoring when you need to insure clients won't be broken if you changed internal logic of the server.